# How can I display Asset Images on Flutter web?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

When I try to display an asset in **Flutter Web** using the following syntax, no image is shown:

```dart
Image.asset(
  'assets/image.png',
)
```

On *mobile*, the same code will show an image.

The structure is as follows:

```
assets
  image.png
lib
  ...
pubspec.yaml
```

In the Pubspec, I declare the asset like this:

```yaml
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/image.png
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All assets are stored in an `assets` directory in Flutter Web, which means that the image asset will be stored like this on web:

```
assets
  assets
    image.png
index.html
...
```

With this knowledge, we can create a widget that handles the behavior for both mobile and web.
Note that we can use `Image.network` on web because the images are accessed through the network on web by default (that is how web works in general). The path would be `yourdomain.com/assets/assets/image.png`.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class PlatformAwareAssetImage extends StatelessWidget {
  const PlatformAwareAssetImage({
    Key key,
    this.asset,
    this.package,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String asset;
  final String package;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      return Image.network(
        'assets/${package == null ? '' : 'packages/$package/'}$asset',
      );
    }

    return Image.asset(
      asset,
      package: package,
    );
  }
}
```

---

Potentially, this will be changed in future Flutter versions - this is the state of things as of `v1.18.0-6.0.pre.82`.

Answer (score 7):

For some reason, assets in the web builds are currently placed under another `assets/` directory, which results in the path being `assets/assets/...`.

Create a simple function e.g. in `lib/utils.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

String path(str) {
  return (kIsWeb) ? 'assets/$str' : str;
}
```

Wrap any path strings with this function, for example `AssetImage(path('images/bg.jpg'))`.

Answer (score 0):

I find this simpler:

```
Image.asset("${(kDebugMode && kIsWeb)?"":"assets/"}images/mds_square.png"),
```

I always need the "assets/" prefix since my "images" folder are in "assets" folder; however, in web debug I need to emit the "assets/" prefix.