# How to load image from assets folder inside a pdf in Flutter web?

Tags: flutter, dart

We want to show image on a pdf from assets folder in Flutter web application:

```
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
.............

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
            height: 400,
            width: 900,
            child: PdfPreview(
              build: (format) => _generatePdf(format, "SOME TITLE"),
            )),
      ),
    ]));
    }

Future<Uint8List> _generatePdf(PdfPageFormat format) async {
final pdf = pw.Document();    
pdf.addPage(
  pw.Page(
      pageFormat: format,
      build: (context) {
        return pw.Image(AssetImage('assets/imglogo.png')); //This line gives the error
      }));
       return pdf.save();
      }
```

This code gives error:

> The argument type 'AssetImage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider'

The [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) addresses only two cases `To load an image from a file:`(`dart.io` is not supported on the web), and `To load an image from the network using the printing package:`, which is not the case, so we tried the solutions provided here: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69069103/error-the-argument-type-pdfimage-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-type-imag),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61301598/how-can-i-display-asset-images-on-flutter-web), but each one gives a different exception.

Is there another approach to achieve this?

Comment: Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: @LajosArpad Updated, the line is: `return pw.Image('assets/imglogo.png'));`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert your `ByteData` directly to `Uint8List` as shown in the example code below. This can then be passed to the `MemoryImage` constructor:

```dart
  Future<void> addPage(pw.Document pdf, String filename) async {
    final imageByteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/$filename');
    // Convert ByteData to Uint8List
    final imageUint8List = imageByteData.buffer
        .asUint8List(imageByteData.offsetInBytes, imageByteData.lengthInBytes);

    final image = pw.MemoryImage(imageUint8List);
    pdf.addPage(
      pw.Page(
        build: (pw.Context context) {
          return pw.Center(
            child: pw.Image(image),
          ); // Center
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Perfect!, just needed to set `height`, `width` and `dpi`. `pw.Image(image, height: 100, width: 100, dpi: 200.0)`.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can get the asset image as a file, and then use this file in the PDF. If I take your code, we can add a function to get a File representation of your asset image :

```dart
  Future<File> getImageFileFromAssets(String path) async {
    final byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/$path');

    final file = File('${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/$path');
    await file.writeAsBytes(byteData.buffer
        .asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes));

    return file;
  }
```

To make it works, you need to add [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages?q=path_provider) to your dependencies.

Then you can use this function in your pdf generation function :

```dart
    final pdf = pw.Document();

    final file = await getImageFileFromAssets(yourpath);

    final image = pw.MemoryImage(
      file.readAsBytesSync(),
    );

    pdf.addPage(pw.Page(
        pageFormat: format,
        build: (context) {
          return pw.Image(image);
        }));
    return pdf.save();
```

Comment: Using this solution, `The following MissingPluginException was thrown while generating a PDF:
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getTemporaryDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)`. NOTE that using `File` requires `import 'dart:io'` which is not supported on flutter web.

Comment: This shouldn't happen (at least not for me), and it's related to path_provider. Try to check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58080990/no-implementation-found-for-method-getapplicationdocumentsdirectory-on-channel-p

Comment: Anyway, I think hnnngwdlch answer's might be better